# get object property, should I throw an exception?

Tags: php, exception

Once I saw someone using the following code for __get method and it seemed elegant so I copied.

```
public function __get($param)
{
    if (!isset($this->params[$param])) {
        throw new Exception("Property doesn't exist");
    }
    return $this->params[$param];
}
```

But now it seems too much to handle an exception when doing a simple action based on whether the property exists or not.
What is the better thing to do in this case. is returning NULL and then checking enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php, this isn't an exceptional circumstance, unlike some other languages. I agree with you in that an exception is too dramatic unless there's special circumstances at play.

I would tend to mimic the expected behavior that is normal in php, which is to return the value of null and [trigger](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) an error of level `E_NOTICE` or `E_USER_NOTICE`. This is the normal behavior when you try to read an undefined property, array indice, or variable.

btw- you might also be intrested in implementing the magic [__isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) method

Answer (score 0):

I would say that returning NULL and checking is enough, although it would depend on what your application does.

If your class creates properties at run time then maybe it's good to throw an exception, but if all the properties exist at compile time then NULL is best.